# Custom brush doesn't maintain continuity

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a brush in Adobe Illustrator. and when I apply that in a circle the shows a start and end point, there is no continuity!

Is there any way to solve it?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Well obviously if the brush enpoints in both ends dont align in y direction they wont hit in the ends wont they. Offcourse you can Use this for your [advantage too](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157436/18306)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't consider this Y axis scenario. Oh dear lord you are sooo right! It makes sense now. Thank you for the attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Art Brushes** have a beginning and an end. They will *always* show this beginning and end.

If you want a continuous brush that appears to have no start/stop you need to use a **Pattern Brush**. Whether you can get the same general appearance from a Pattern Brush is another matter. In this case, I suspect one could create the middle brush pattern with a very long piece.

If one is merely seeking some width variation in strokes, it's often easiest to *not* use a brush and set a **Profile** for strokes in the **Stroke Panel**.

Comment: Thank you Scott.